# Show a free abelian group with one generator

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $I=[0,1],X=I/\{0,1\}$.Prove that $\pi_1(X,\bar{0})$ is a free abelian group with one generator.

I note that $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ given by $h(x)=(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x))$,then the fundamental group of $X$ and $S^1$ based at $\bar{0}$ is equal and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Then, I'm wondering what is exactly the one generator that generates the free abelian group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb Z$ has $1$ as a generator;   the other generator is $-1$.

Comment: I know that 1 generates $\mathbb{Z}$.But can I say the homotopy class $[\alpha]$ where the path $\alpha (t) = (cos(2\pi t),sin(2\pi t))$ generates the other free abelian group?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a generator,  since it goes around once.  It corresponds to $1$.

Comment: But the element in the group is homotopy class,is it supposed to be $[\alpha]$ be the generator?

Comment: Yes.  Sloppy on my part.

Comment: No problem.Thank you for your confirmation!